# Nautilus Raw thumbnail (ufraw) - Bug found in archives

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, bug-reporting, thumbnails

I have followed many tutorials around the internet and basically they say:

Install ufraw -> Done

Create file at */usr/share/thumbnailers/**something.thumbnailer*** with content:

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
Exec=/usr/bin/ufraw-batch --embedded-image --out-type=png --size=%s %u --overwrite --silent --output=%o
MimeType=image/x-3fr;image/x-adobe-dng;image/x-arw;image/x-bay;image/x-canon-cr2;image/x-canon-crw;image/x-cap;image/x-cr2;image/x-crw;image/x-dcr;image/x-dcraw;image/x-dcs;image/x-dng;image/x-drf;image/x-eip;image/x-erf;image/x-fff;image/x-fuji-raf;image/x-iiq;image/x-k25;image/x-kdc;image/x-mef;image/x-minolta-mrw;image/x-mos;image/x-mrw;image/x-nef;image/x-nikon-nef;image/x-nrw;image/x-olympus-orf;image/x-orf;image/x-panasonic-raw;image/x-pef;image/x-pentax-pef;image/x-ptx;image/x-pxn;image/x-r3d;image/x-raf;image/x-raw;image/x-rw2;image/x-rwl;image/x-rwz;image/x-sigma-x3f;image/x-sony-arw;image/x-sony-sr2;image/x-sony-srf;image/x-sr2;image/x-srf;image/x-x3f;
```

I have cleared all nautilus thumb cache and, when the folder with the raw files are opened, I get a little time clock on each file at a time showing that something is been done.

The thumbs are still black

The folder .../thumbnails/**fail**/gnome-thumbnail-factory is now filled with .png files, but the images have only one small dot at the center. The other folders such **large** and **normal** are empty.

I have removed and re-installed ufraw many times and tried many different (but similar) [Thumbnailer Entry]

Don't know what else to do...

**My guess: find out why the generated thumbs are failing, but don't even know where to start.**

One more thing: even if I change the output format in [Thumbnailer Entry] syntax it still generate a png file at the fail folder.

Does ufraw-batch generate a log file?

Any help would be appreciated.

> UPDATE! Found the system log. Posting just a few lines, but it goes on and on. Don't know how to interpret it

```
Mar  6 16:31:16 ricardo-linux kernel: [ 4976.217518] ufraw-batch[4136]: segfault at 38 ip 00007f0a16a3bb64 sp 00007ffe5d53f1d0 error 4 in liblensfun.so.0.3.2[7f0a16a28000+1a000]
Mar  6 16:31:17 ricardo-linux kernel: [ 4976.576625] ufraw-batch[4141]: segfault at 38 ip 00007f4c8c183b64 sp 00007ffe0da51d90 error 4 in liblensfun.so.0.3.2[7f4c8c170000+1a000]
Mar  6 16:31:17 ricardo-linux kernel: [ 4976.934196] ufraw-batch[4145]: segfault at 38 ip 00007eff47ad3b64 sp 00007ffc9481d000 error 4 in liblensfun.so.0.3.2[7eff47ac0000+1a000]
Mar  6 16:31:18 ricardo-linux kernel: [ 4977.298066] ufraw-batch[4149]: segfault at 38 ip 00007f25674cbb64 sp 00007ffd637eab60 error 4 in liblensfun.so.0.3.2[7f25674b8000+1a000]
Mar  6 16:31:18 ricardo-linux kernel: [ 4977.651138] ufraw-batch[4153]: segfault at 38 ip 00007f37e3f83b64 sp 00007ffdfe2bedd0 error 4 in liblensfun.so.0.3.2[7f37e3f70000+1a000]
Mar  6 16:31:18 ricardo-linux kernel: [ 4978.056727] ufraw-batch[4157]: segfault at 38 ip 00007f69390abb64 sp 00007ffefead1690 error 4 in liblensfun.so.0.3.2[7f6939098000+1a000]
Mar  6 16:31:19 ricardo-linux kernel: [ 4978.419980] ufraw-batch[4161]: segfault at 38 ip 00007fb5f1afbb64 sp 00007ffd770103e0 error 4 in liblensfun.so.0.3.2[7fb5f1ae8000+1a000]
Mar  6 16:31:19 ricardo-linux kernel: [ 4978.702822] ufraw-batch[4165]: segfault at 38 ip 00007fa6b93c3b64 sp 00007ffe9ff1aaf0 error 4 in liblensfun.so.0.3.2[7fa6b93b0000+1a000]
Mar  6 16:31:19 ricardo-linux kernel: [ 4978.997531] ufraw-batch[4169]: segfault at 38 ip 00007f9f21b23b64 sp 00007ffcf9442be0 error 4 in liblensfun.so.0.3.2[7f9f21b10000+1a000]
Mar  6 16:31:20 ricardo-linux kernel: [ 4979.369336] ufraw-batch[4173]: segfault at 38 ip 00007f6337613b64 sp 00007ffee6a425f0 error 4 in liblensfun.so.0.3.2[7f6337600000+1a000]
```

> UPDATE2 - Its a bug
>   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ufraw/+bug/1768855

I'm sad now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and kept trying until I found a solution.

1) Install from debian repo (older version of liblensfun):

- [liblensfun-data_0.2.8-2_all.deb](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/liblensfun-data/download)
- [liblensfun0 (0.2.8-2)](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/liblensfun0)

2) Delete symbolic link /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblensfun.so.1 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblensfun.so.0.3.2

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblensfun.so.1
```

3) Create new symbolic link to older version

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/liblensfun.so.0.2.8 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblensfun.so.1
```

** UPDATE **
This solution broke Rawtherapee (which I use to edit the raw files).

New solution: [liblensfun1_0.3.2-3](https://debian.pkgs.org/9/debian-main-amd64/liblensfun1_0.3.2-3_amd64.deb.html) (1 minor version back) does the trick